# Suggestions dropdown for Vaadin TextField

Tags: vaadin

How can we add like say google email search, a down arrow icon or even just the function of the down arrow to the Text Field?[image: Currently, I'm using autocompletetexField.]

The issue is in this component is, It shows suggestion when I start typing. I need to show all suggestions on focus or a down arrow, when I click down arrow it will show all the suggestions. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could use a ComboBox with a data provider https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-combo-box/java-examples

Comment: Combobox is used for selection but here is my scenario is different. I'll type more text after select any of the above options.

Comment: Then have a look at Vaadin Component Directory https://vaadin.com/directory/search What about https://vaadin.com/directory/component/vaadinincubator-autocomplete

Comment: `ComboBox<String>` is definitely the way to go here. The user *can* pick an item from the dropdown, but he can also start typing which starts filtering the dropdown items. If the desired item doesn't exist yet in the list, the user can enter his own value which is then added to the list. See [example codes](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-combo-box/java-examples#custom-value-box) under "Allow Custom Values" and "Storing Custom Values"